# Empty FILES array for large (ish) file uploads

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

I've got some legacy code that for the life of me I cant see why it's suddenly stopped working.

Very basic upload script:

```
if($_FILES['csvfile']['name']){
    //if no errors...
    if(!$_FILES['csvfile']['error']){
        //now is the time to modify the future fle name and validate the file
        $new_file_name = strtolower($_FILES['csvfile']['tmp_name']); //rename file


       //move it to where we want it to be
       move_uploaded_file($_FILES['csvfile']['tmp_name'], 'active_leads1.csv');
       //echo 'Congratulations!  Your file was accepted.';

    }else{
      //set that to be the returned message
      //echo 'Ooops!  Your upload triggered the following error:  '.$_FILES['csvfile']['error'];

       die("Unfortuanatly there was an error: {$_FILES['csvfile']['error']}");
   }
}else{
    die("Unfortuanatly there was an error: ".print_r($_FILES,true)."");

}
```

And equally the form is just as basic:

```
<form action="csvconvert.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="csvfile" size="25" />
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And yet, it fails on a file c. 11MB. Smaller files are ok.

Checked the post limit and upload limit, both are fine (256M and 128M), max input time is 240, and yet if I print_r $_POST and $_FILES they are both empty.

Has anyone come across this before? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Which error do you have? Does the code fallback to one of your error messages?

Comment: check using if(isset($_POST)) { print_r($_FILES); }, if you are getting files

Comment: Hi, As mentioned in my post, print_r on $_POST and $_FILES returns an empty array, so I'm not getting the submit button come through either.

Answer (score 0):

If smaller files are ok, are you sure your `upload_max_filesize` is larger than 11MB? What is the value of `upload_max_filesize` when you use `echo phpinfo();`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however as noted in my post, upload_max_filesize is set to 128MB, and post_max_size is set to 256MB

Comment: That's odd. Then the only thing i can think of is maybe the `max_input_time` value is to small. What's the value of this?

Comment: 240, and the upload is taking around a minute - this is why I'm stumped too!